# SSIS C# Script Task to Clean SQL Records

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to piece together a C# script in SSIS to do the steps below:

1. Establish a SQL Server connection
2. Either read the entire contents of a SQL Server table into a `DataTable`, or process on a row by row basis and export to a new table (not sure which method to use....)
3. Search through each column in a row, and if that row has a length of 1 and has a value of '-', replace the dash with NULL.  They key here is that I do not want to declare each of the column names.
4. Then write the records back out to another SQL Server table.

I am new to C# so I am looking for the most simple way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, as a new member to our community please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page, so that you have a better feel for what StackOverflow is all about and how to properly ask a question here.  Please Edit your Question to show us what you have tried with some code snippets.

Comment: If you're using SSIS, this could also be done as an {EXECUTE SQL TASK}, as I don't see anything you've listed as something only C# can do (since you're **new** to C#).

Comment: For what you are describing, you aren't using SSIS as it should be. Your approach, while valid for a .NET app or library, isn't using SSIS to do what's it's designed for.

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS approach to doing what you describe is

1. Add an OLE DB Connection Manager to your package that points to the source server
2. Add a Data Flow Task onto your Contro Flow
3. Write a `SELECT` statement that pulls back the columns that meet your criteria. `SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.MyTable T WHERE T.col1 = '-' OR T.col2 = '-';` Actual implementation may vary. Put that query inside an OLE DB Source Component
4. Add a Derived Column Component to turn the - into a NULL value
5. Add an OLE DB Destination to write to the new table

However, an even better approach would be to not store this data as such and keep it clean before landing it in your table. Baring that, I'd probably look at using an Execute SQL Task to fire off a query to clean the data on the server. No need to do row by row processing. You describe the set (anything with a length of 1 and a value of `-`) so fix the set (`UPDATE T SET col1 = NULLIF(Col1, '-'), ... FROM dbo.MyTable T`)